# DeleteDuplicateBy: positions to delete

Tags: list-manipulation, numerical-integration, interpolation

I need to obtain numerically the following interpolation function by integration:

```
f22 = Table[{Re[
     NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[1 - (0.5/r)^2], {r, 0, x}, 
      Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}]], 
    x}, {x, 0, 20, .01}];
f2 = DeleteDuplicatesBy[f22, First];
f = Interpolation[f2] 
f[0]
```

I know that the analytical result of this integral is  $f(r)=\sqrt{r^2+(0.5)^2}$, hence `f[0]=0.5`, but the interpolation results into `f[0]=0`. Without the  `DeleteDuplicates` this list has the following duplicate points

```
{{0.,0.},{0.,0.01},{0.,0.02},..., {0., 0.49}, {0., 0.5}}}
```

After the `DeleteDuplicates`, the only element that survives is `{0.,0.}`, but it should be `{0., 0.5}`.

There is an option in `DeleteDuplicatesBy` that preserve the last one element, rather the first?

Comment: The analytical result you suggest is wrong (it's derivative is $1/\sqrt{r^2+0.25}$). Btw your integrand is not defined over the reals if $r\leq 0.5$. Lastly, the integral of a smooth function from 0 to 0 is 0.

Comment: @anderstood `Simplify[Integrate[1/Sqrt[1 - (1/(2 r))^2], r], Assumptions -> r >= 0]` returns `1/2 Sqrt[-1 + 4 r^2]`, and `D[Sqrt[r^2 - (0.5)^2], r]` returns `r/Sqrt[-0.25 + r^2]`. The OP is right.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Where is the minus sign in the OP? I read $\sqrt{r^2+0.5^2}$. Moreover, `1/Sqrt[1 - (1/(2 r))^2]` is not real-valued if $0<r<1/2$.

Comment: @anderstood My apologies, somehow I misread the OP's antiderivative. And it seems `NIntegrate` applies `Re` to the result under the hood without warnings... So the output of `NIntegrate` isn't correct for $0<r<1/2$?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I guess the complex values returned by `NIntegrate` are correct (considering the principal square root), but I am not sure if the OP understands what he is doing. Anyway, the answer was accepted so I don't think it matters (from the SE point of view...).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you can use [`Reverse`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reverse.html):

```
r1 = Reverse @ DeleteDuplicatesBy[Reverse @ f22, First]
```

Possibly more robustly you might [`GatherBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html) or [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html) the elements, then keep whichever ones you want.

```
r2 = Last /@ Sort /@ GatherBy[f22, First]

r3 = GroupBy[f22, First, Last@*Sort] // Values
```

The match in this case:

```
r1 === r2 === r3
```

> ```
> True
> ```